# Why isn't it possible to use try-with-resource in that case?

Tags: java, resources, try-catch

The following code works fine:

```
String connStr = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/addressbook";

try ( Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connStr, "root", "");
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from contact where firstName=?");
        ) {

    ps.setString(1, "Cippo");
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()) {
        System.out.print(rs.getString(2) + "\t");
        System.out.print(rs.getString(3) + "\t");
        System.out.print(rs.getInt(1) + "\t");
        System.out.print(rs.getString(4) + "\t");
        System.out.println(rs.getString(5));                    
    }

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

But for a mysterious reason when I move other two instructions into the try-with-resource block (where they are supposed to stay), I get a compilation error:

```
String connStr = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/addressbook";

try ( Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connStr, "root", "");
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from contact where firstName=?");
        ps.setString(1, "Cippo");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        ) { 

    while(rs.next()) {
        System.out.print(rs.getString(2) + "\t");
        System.out.print(rs.getString(3) + "\t");
        System.out.print(rs.getInt(1) + "\t");
        System.out.print(rs.getString(4) + "\t");
        System.out.println(rs.getString(5));                    
    }

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

The compilation error is irreasonable: "ps cannot be resolved". But conn is resolved without any problem. Why that?

Comment: I think you cannot do anything other than assignment operations in the `try(...)` part, but I'm not sure. so your codesnipet: `ps.setString(1, "Cippo")` is in an invalid place.

Answer (score 0):

The try with resources syntax is for assigning objects that implement [autocloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) such as streams and database connections so that they can be correctly cleaned up in the event of an exception. It's not designed for executing arbitrary additional code.

I don't really see what you were trying to achieve by placing those two instructions inside the allocation section of the try statement as you have achieved the same result with the first example.

Update: I wonder if you are placing the `ResultSet` in  the try so that it will automatically be closed on failure. If that is the case then I believe it should be closed automatically by the call to close on the statement object. If you are concerned a separate inner try with resources for the `ResultSet` would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

That's just how the Java syntax is defined:

From the  [**Java Language Specification, Section 14.20.3 try-with-resources**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3)

> A try-with-resources statement is parameterized with variables (known
>   as resources) that are initialized before execution of the try block
>   and closed automatically, in the reverse order from which they were
>   initialized, after execution of the try block.
>   [...]
>
> A *ResourceSpecification* declares one or more local variables with
>   initializer expressions to act as resources for the try statement.

Answer (score 0):

AutoCloseable http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html are closed before catching any of inner exception. So it is not possilbe to place AutoCloeable in try-resource block and also inside the try block.